# Error al cargar JSON en React.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, reactjs

Hola Estoy haciendo un curso de React.js usando Node. Intento traer un archivo JSON que contiene una lista de películas para una pagina que se supone es para comprar películas. El JSON está en esta url :"https://lucasmoy.dev/data/react/peliculas.json", y cuando se efectúa la solicitud al servidor esta se ejecuta correctamente (código http 200). Si en la consola verifico el archivo este se puede leer:

[image: Consola del navegador]

Pero, cuando intento utilizar el archivo me genera el siguiente error:

[image: Error en la linea 29]

Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input

Aquí dejo el codigo (el error está en App.js):

```js
export default function PageWrapper(props){

    return (
         <div>
             
             <div id="preloader">
    <img className="logo" src="images/logo1.png" alt="" width="119" height="58"/>
    <div id="status">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div className="login-wrapper" id="login-content">
    <div className="login-content">
        <a href="#" className="close">x</a>
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <form method="post" action="#">
            <div className="row">
                 <label for="username">
                    Username:
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Hugh Jackman" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{8,20}$" required="required" />
                </label>
            </div>
           
            <div className="row">
                <label for="password">
                    Password:
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="******" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required="required" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="remember">
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="Remember me"/><span>Remember me</span>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#">Forget password ?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           <div className="row">
             <button type="submit">Login</button>
           </div>
        </form>
        <div className="row">
            <p>Or via social</p>
            <div className="social-btn-2">
                <a className="fb" href="#"><i className="ion-social-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>
                <a className="tw" href="#"><i className="ion-social-twitter"></i>twitter</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div className="login-wrapper"  id="signup-content">
    <div className="login-content">
        <a href="#" className="close">x</a>
        <h3>sign up</h3>
        <form method="post" action="#">
            <div className="row">
                 <label for="username-2">
                    Username:
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username-2" placeholder="Hugh Jackman" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{8,20}$" required="required" />
                </label>
            </div>
           
            <div className="row">
                <label for="email-2">
                    your email:
                    <input type="password" name="email" id="email-2" placeholder="" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required="required" />
                </label>
            </div>
             <div className="row">
                <label for="password-2">
                    Password:
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password-2" placeholder="" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required="required" />
                </label>
            </div>
             <div className="row">
                <label for="repassword-2">
                    re-type Password:
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="repassword-2" placeholder="" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required="required" />
                </label>
            </div>
           <div className="row">
             <button type="submit">sign up</button>
           </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<header className="ht-header">
    <div className="container">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
            
                <div className="navbar-header logo">
                    <div className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <div id="nav-icon1">
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="index-2.html"><img className="logo" src="images/logo1.png" alt="" width="119" height="58"/></a>
                </div>
                
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse flex-parent" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul className="nav navbar-nav flex-child-menu menu-left">
                        <li className="hidden">
                            <a href="#page-top"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="dropdown first">
                            <a className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle lv1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Home <i className="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu level1">
                                <li><a href="index-2.html">Home 01</a></li>
                                <li><a href="homev2.html">Home 02</a></li>
                                <li><a href="homev3.html">Home 03</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li className="dropdown first">
                            <a className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle lv1" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
                            movies<i className="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu level1">
                                <li className="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Movie grid<i className="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i></a>
                                    <ul className="dropdown-menu level2">
                                        <li><a href="moviegrid.html">Movie grid</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="moviegridfw.html">movie grid full width</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>           
                                <li><a href="movielist.html">Movie list</a></li>
                                <li><a href="moviesingle.html">Movie single</a></li>
                                <li className="it-last"><a href="seriessingle.html">Series single</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li className="dropdown first">
                            <a className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle lv1" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
                            celebrities <i className="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu level1">
                                <li><a href="celebritygrid01.html">celebrity grid 01</a></li>
                                <li><a href="celebritygrid02.html">celebrity grid 02 </a></li>
                                <li><a href="celebritylist.html">celebrity list</a></li>
                                <li className="it-last"><a href="celebritysingle.html">celebrity single</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li className="dropdown first">
                            <a className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle lv1" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
                            news <i className="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu level1">
                                <li><a href="bloglist.html">blog List</a></li>
                                <li><a href="bloggrid.html">blog Grid</a></li>
                                <li className="it-last"><a href="blogdetail.html">blog Detail</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li className="dropdown first">
                            <a className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle lv1" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
                            community <i className="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu level1">
                                <li><a href="userfavoritegrid.html">user favorite grid</a></li>
                                <li><a href="userfavoritelist.html">user favorite list</a></li>
                                <li><a href="userprofile.html">user profile</a></li>
                                <li className="it-last"><a href="userrate.html">user rate</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul className="nav navbar-nav flex-child-menu menu-right">
                        <li className="dropdown first">
                            <a className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle lv1" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
                            pages <i className="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu level1">
                                <li><a href="landing.html">Landing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="404.html">404 Page</a></li>
                                <li className="it-last"><a href="comingsoon.html">Coming soon</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                
                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                        <li className="loginLink"><a href="#">LOG In</a></li>
                        <li className="btn signupLink"><a href="#">sign up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        
        </nav>
        

        <div className="top-search">
            <select>
                <option value="united">TV show</option>
                <option value="saab">Others</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a movie, TV Show or celebrity that you are looking for"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div className="hero common-hero">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <div className="hero-ct">
                    <h1> movie listing - list</h1>
                    <ul className="breadcumb">
                        <li className="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li> <span className="ion-ios-arrow-right"></span> movie listing</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div className="page-single movie_list">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row ipad-width2">
            <div className="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div className="topbar-filter">
                    <p>Found <span>1,608 movies</span> in total</p>
                    <label>Sort by:</label>
                    <select>
                        <option value="popularity">Popularity Descending</option>
                        <option value="popularity">Popularity Ascending</option>
                        <option value="rating">Rating Descending</option>
                        <option value="rating">Rating Ascending</option>
                        <option value="date">Release date Descending</option>
                        <option value="date">Release date Ascending</option>
                    </select>
                    <a href="movielist.html" className="list"><i className="ion-ios-list-outline active"></i></a>
                    <a  href="moviegrid.html" className="grid"><i className="ion-grid"></i></a>
                </div>
                           
                           {props.children}
                
            
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div className="sidebar">
                    <div className="searh-form">
                        <h4 className="sb-title">Search for movie</h4>
                        <form className="form-style-1" action="#">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-12 form-it">
                                    <label>Movie name</label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter keywords"/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-12 form-it">
                                    <label>Genres & Subgenres</label>
                                    <div className="group-ip">
                                        <select
                                            name="skills" multiple="" className="ui fluid dropdown">
                                            <option value="">Enter to filter genres</option>
                                            <option value="Action1">Action 1</option>
                                            <option value="Action2">Action 2</option>
                                            <option value="Action3">Action 3</option>
                                            <option value="Action4">Action 4</option>
                                            <option value="Action5">Action 5</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-12 form-it">
                                    <label>Rating Range</label>
                                    
                                     <select>
                                        <option value="range">-- Select the rating range below --</option>
                                        <option value="saab">-- Select the rating range below --</option>
                                        <option value="saab">-- Select the rating range below --</option>
                                        <option value="saab">-- Select the rating range below --</option>
                                    </select>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-12 form-it">
                                    <label>Release Year</label>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-md-6">
                                            <select>
                                                <option value="range">From</option>
                                                <option value="number">10</option>
                                                <option value="number">20</option>
                                                <option value="number">30</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-md-6">
                                            <select>
                                                <option value="range">To</option>
                                                <option value="number">20</option>
                                                <option value="number">30</option>
                                                <option value="number">40</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-12 ">
                                    <input className="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className="ads">
                        <img src="images/uploads/ads1.png" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sb-facebook sb-it">
                        <h4 className="sb-title">Find us on Facebook</h4>
                        <iframe src="#" data-src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ftemplatespoint.net%2F%3Ffref%3Dts&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=315px&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=false&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId"  height="315"></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sb-twitter sb-it">
                        <h4 className="sb-title">Tweet to us</h4>
                        <div className="slick-tw">
                            <div className="tweet item" id="">
                            </div>
                            <div className="tweet item" id="">
                            </div>
                        </div>                          
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer className="ht-footer">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="flex-parent-ft">
            <div className="flex-child-ft item1">
                 <a href="index-2.html"><img className="logo" src="images/logo1.png" alt=""/></a>
                 <p>5th Avenue st, manhattan<br/>
                New York, NY 10001</p>
                <p>Call us: <a href="#">(+01) 202 342 6789</a></p>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-child-ft item2">
                <h4>Resources</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Blockbuster</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help Center</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-child-ft item3">
                <h4>Legal</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Security</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-child-ft item4">
                <h4>Account</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Watchlist</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#">Collections</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">User Guide</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-child-ft item5">
                <h4>Newsletter</h4>
                <p>Subscribe to our newsletter system now <br/> to get latest news from us.</p>
                <form action="#">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email..."/>
                </form>
                <a href="#" className="btn">Subscribe now <i className="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="ft-copyright">
        <div className="ft-left">
            <p><a target="_blank" href="https://www.templateshub.net">Templates Hub</a></p>
        </div>
        <div className="backtotop">
            <p><a href="#" id="back-to-top">Back to top  <i className="ion-ios-arrow-thin-up"></i></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>


         </div>
  );
}
```

```js
export default function paginacion(props){

    const getPags = ()=>{
        const resultado =[];

        for (let i = 0; i < props.total; i++) {
           
            resultado.push(
            <a onClick={()=>props.onChange(i+1)}
             className={props.pagina === (i+1) ? "active" : ''} >
                {(i+1)}
                </a>);
            
        }
         return resultado;
      }

    return (
        
        <div className="topbar-filter">

        <div className="pagination2">
            <span>Pagina {props.pagina} de {props.total}:</span>
          
            {getPags()}
        </div>
    </div>
    
    )
}
```

```js
export default function Pelicula(props){
      
   return   (<div className="movie-item-style-2">
   <img src={props.img} alt=""/>
   <div className="mv-item-infor">
       <h6><a href="moviesingle.html">{props.titulo}<span> ({props.anho})</span></a></h6>
       <p className="rate"><i className="ion-android-star"></i><span>{props.calificacion}</span> /10</p>
       <p className="describe">{props.descripcion}</p>
       <p className="run-time"> Duracion: {props.duracion}   .     <span>MMPA: {props.clasificacion}</span> . <span>Estreno: {props.lanzamiento}</span></p>
       <p>Director/es: {props.director} </p>
       <p>Protagonistas: {props.actores} </p>
   </div>
</div>
   )

}
```

AQUI ESTA EL ARCHIVO EN EL CUAL ESTA EL ERROR

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Pelicula from './pelicula';
import PageWrapper from './PageWrapper';
import Paginacion from './Paginacion';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

    

    const [paginaActual, setPaginaActual] = useState(1);
    const[peliculas, setPeliculas] = useState([]);
    
    const TOTAL_PAGINA = 5;
    const buscarPelicula=async()=>{
        let url ='https://lucasmoy.dev/data/react/peliculas.json';
        
        let respuesta = await fetch(url,{
            "method":'GET',
            "mode":'no-cors',
            "headers":{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            
            }
        });
            debugger;
           //aqui es donde se genera el error
           let json = await respuesta.json();
          
           setPeliculas(json);
    }

    const cargarPeliculas=()=>{
    //  peliculas = peliculas.slice((paginaActual-1)*TOTAL_PAGINA,paginaActual*TOTAL_PAGINA);
    }
    
    const getTotalPags =()=>{
        let totalMovies = peliculas.length;
        return Math.ceil(totalMovies/TOTAL_PAGINA);
    }

  
    cargarPeliculas();
     
  return (

    <PageWrapper>

     <button onClick={buscarPelicula}>Prueba</button>

    {peliculas.map(pelicula=>
         <Pelicula titulo={pelicula.titulo} calificacion={pelicula.calificacion} anho={pelicula.anho} duracion={pelicula.duracion}
        clasificacion={pelicula.clasificacion} director={pelicula.director} descripcion={pelicula.descripcion}
        
        actores={pelicula.actores.map(actor=>
            <a href="#">{actor} </a>)} 
        lanzamiento={pelicula.lanzamiento} img={pelicula.img}>
        
        </Pelicula>
    )}

    <Paginacion pagina ={paginaActual} total={getTotalPags()} onChange={(pagina)=>{
        setPaginaActual(pagina)
    }}/>

    </PageWrapper>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: en cual parte de todo este codigo esta el problema? mira por favor [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

cuanto es un `GET` no es necesario especificarlo en la cabecera como `method`, y otra cosa, debes habilitar el acceso a tu backend para que no tengas problemas con el cors

```
const buscarPelicula=async()=>{
  let url ='https://lucasmoy.dev/data/react/peliculas.json';
  let respuesta = await fetch(url);
  debugger;
  //aqui es donde se genera el error
  let json = await respuesta.json();
  setPeliculas(json);
}
```

Comment: Disculpa mí ignorancia, pero como se habilita el acceso al backend de mí proyecto?

Comment: @LautaroAcuña que backend estas usando, php, nodejs, net core o cual es, solo buscas informacion sobre cors y te aparecen muchas opciones, pero supongo que la api es publica, lo cual no tendrias ningun problema, probe desde mi maquina y funciona perfecto.

Comment: Nodejs estoy usando

Comment: @LautaroAcuña puedes revisar la documentacion de npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors o express https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.htm, las dos estan bien documentada